# Exposing a docker container to the internet

Tags: docker, port, router

I deployed a ghost blogging platform on my server using docker. Now I want to expose it to the internet but I'm having some difficulties doing so.

I opened port `8000` in my router a forwarded it to port `32769` which is the one assign to that container. Using port `32769` inside my network I can access the website fine but when I try to access it from the internet it gives a `took too long to respond` error.

Local IP + PORT: `http://10.0.0.140:32769/`

#### Docker port config

[image]

#### Port tester

[image]

#### Router settings

[image]

This post was also added to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1631751/exposing-a-docker-container-to-the-internet) since it has been said that it would be responded better in there.

Comment: Running into the same problem, and trying to provide more info on how to solve it. One step that got me more information was getting the id of the container and looking at the logfiles using this: https://everythingtech.dev/2021/08/how-to-access-wordpress-logs-from-docker That confirmed the docker container is being accessed from the outside and it's probablt the return traffic that gets lost somehow. From the local network, I can access it and I get results. I know, from the log files from the container, that the request from the web reaches the container, but from outside I get no response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your application inside docker is now working on port 8000
You want to expose your application to internet.
The request would go: internet -> router -> physical computer (host machine) -> docker.

1. You need to export your application to your host machine, this could be done via `EXPOSE 8000` instruction in Dockerfile.
   That port should be accessible from your host machine first, so, when starting your docker image as docker container, you should add `-p` parameter, such as
   `sudo docker run -d -it -p 8000:8000 --name docker_contaier_name docker_image_name`
   From now on, your docker application can be access within your host machine, let's say it is your physical computer.
2. Forward port from your router to your host machine
   This time, you may want to do as what you did in your question.
3. Access your application from internet.
   If I am thinking correctly, the ip address `10.0.0.140` is just your computer LAN IP address, it cannot accessible from internet.
   You can only able to connect to your app via an internet IP, to do that, you can check your router to see what is your WAN IP address, which will be assigned to your router by your internet service provider. Or go google with "what is my IP"

Comment: I dont know if I'm missing something. I changed the port to 8080 since 8000 was being used by portainer and opened the ports in the router but still can't open the website from outside the network. Now inside portainer port configuration is 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 2368/tcp

Comment: Is expose 8080 a different thing from the port configuration?

Comment: Do I need to add EXPOSE 8080 besides the port config? How can i access the docker file of a repo that is not mine?

Comment: ITS WORKING. Dont know wy but used my phone and it worked

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, more or less, is setting up Apache2 as reverse proxy, redirecting a path in Apache2 to the port of the Docker container. This probably could also be done for example with NGINX.
This way the traffic from the net gets proxied to the container and back to the net, and I see the WordPress site. So regarding the question of OP, the docker container is now exposed to the internet.

However 1: This still doesn't explain why I don't get return traffic from the Docker container if I access it directly from the net.

However 2: Not all the url's in the WordPress site are correct, but that seems to be a WordPress issue and not a Docker / routing issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).