# How to make namenode container in the Hadoop to access to network in the Docker?

Tags: docker, hadoop, dns

I am new to Docker network configure and Hadoop, based on this tutorial [Set Up Containerize and Test a Single Hadoop Cluster using Docker and Docker compose](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/set-up-containerize-and-test-a-single-hadoop-cluster-using-docker-and-docker-compose/), how to configure to make namenode access the Internet such as Google?

It doesn't work even though I have add

```
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"],
    "iptables":false
```

into `~/.docker/daemon.json`, and change `/etc/resolv.conf` the dns to `8.8.8.8`.

```
$ cat ~/.docker/daemon.json 
{
    "builder": { "gc": { "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB", "enabled": true } },
    "experimental": false,
    "features": { "buildkit": true },
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"],
    "iptables":false
}
```

Refer:
[Exposing a docker container to the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527816/exposing-a-docker-container-to-the-internet)

[How can I make docker-compose bind the containers only on defined network instead of 0.0.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109398/how-can-i-make-docker-compose-bind-the-containers-only-on-defined-network-instea)

https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: 1. Docker uses your Host DNS, and therefore doesn't need modified. 2) Hadoop doesn't need to reach the open internet, and [this is not recommended](https://thehackernews.com/2017/06/secure-hadoop-cluster.html) 3) You'd use HTTP clients to access Google like curl/wget; what does that have to do with DNS/iptables?